# Player with changeable speed

Tags: 8.0, audio, mediaplayer

I need to find an audio player app that can change the playback speed (slower and faster). Does anyone know an app that can do this?

Comment: what kind of player are you after? video? music? something else?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I need to player, wich can play audio.
I don't need music player(this files is not music), but I think music player also be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC](https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/store/apps/vlc-for-windows-phone/9wzdncrcv5tl) allows you to change the speed of reproduction from **0.5x** to **2x**, as you can see in this image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I can't find the way to change speed on my smartphone (Nokia Lumia 1020). I wiil be very thankful, if you tell me know how to do it.

Comment: Did you installed VLC as I suggested? Then just open VLC, choose a video to play and click on the "..." simbol; the speed option will show, like in the image I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Audiobooked](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=b13676da-9760-461a-9079-9bbaa7a47d17) is an app designed for audio-books, with speed control, bookmarks and more.

Answer (score 1):

[Unotune player](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/unotune-music-player/9nblggh5wq5z) allows a changeable audio playback rate while preserving the pitch.